# Derivativation of definite integral

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

Having:

$f = \int_0^{n}{X_{(t)}dt} + X_{n}$

How can I find:

$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{n}} = ?$

Please note that the derivative is done with respect to one of the ends of the integral. (hope that's clear English)

Thanks!

Comment: Derivativation?

Comment: Yes... what's your question? If that's not proper English then that's because I'm not native :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\int_a^x g(t)dt\right) = g(x).$$ Use this theorem to differentiate the right side of the equation you gave and then solve for $\frac{\partial X}{\partial n}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}$ and $X(n)$.

Comment: It looks so obvious when I read the answer, thanks! :)

Comment: Full explanation can be found here: http://mathmistakes.info/facts/CalculusFacts/learn/doi/doi.html